# Using montouch to embed a SegmentControl into the header of a UIViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using monotouch and have created a UIViewController. I want to add SegmentControl to the header of the view.

Within the call settings on the iphone under recents is exactly what I am trying to do. I have managed to create the segmentcontrol within the interface builder but I have no clue how to move it into the header.

Can anyone help out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some good examples of the SegmentControl in various positions in the Monotouch Samples, particularly the 'catalog' sample: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MonoCatalogSample

The 'toolbar' section is a worked example of a segment control at the top of a view and the segments section shows how to customise it.  Check the others too, as multiple segment controls are used in the date picker and other sections.

From my (very limited) experience with MT so far, I recommend creating elements programmatically rather than via IB; having control over element layout can be easier that way.

Cheers